# Disabling super (windows) keybinding in Ubuntu-12.04

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-12.04

As an emacs user, I would like to have <super> generally available to me as a modifier. I've had some success in disabling Ubuntu's default hotkeys, but am having trouble with <super>-s. The default behavior is to launch the workspace switcher, and I haven't found a way to change that. I've been using CompizConfig Settings Manager for my successful changes.

Comment: I can't verify right now, but you may find http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ can help you with that, if you look under the "Unity Settings" options.

Comment: Ah, `ccsm` (as per juanleon's answer) was what I was thinking of. Still, the tweak utility is also useful, so I'm leaving the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`)
2. Start it (`ccsm`) and go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Behavior
3. Disable the keybinding "Key to starts the switcher"

If that does not work, go for the hard way:

1. Start `gconf-editor`
2. Edit->Find.  Search for `<Super>s` (with the <>), with the "Search also in key values" option clicked.
3. Edit the matches at your leisure

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that I did have some success with compizconfig-settings-manager. In the Unity Plugin Behavior pane, I don't see any setting for the workspace switcher.

Comment: Strange.  I think I got rid of that keybinding that way (but I got rid of so many that maybe I misremember for this particular one).  I added another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't (want to) have compizconfig-settings-manager installed, you can use

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_launcher" --type string ""
```

to disable the key mapping

( http://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2 )

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. Or at least it doesn't have the effect that I'm hoping for (unbinding <super>-s).